# C++ struct dynamic array containing dynamic array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, dynamic

I am trying to create a stuct with dynamic float array, and then create a dynamic array of that struct, but sometimes the result of calling one of the float returns nulptr while other times it works normally and I can not understand why.
here's my code

```
struct ColumnData {
    float* data{};
    int type{};

    static ColumnData* Create(std::size_t sampleSize) {
        return new ColumnData[sampleSize];
    }
};
```

---

```
ColumData *learningData;
learningData = ColumData::Create(sampleSize);

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < sampleSize; i++) {
        learningData[i].data = new float[dataPerSample];
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < dataPerSample; j++)
        {
            std::cin >> learningData[i].data[j];
        }
        std::cin >> learningData[i].type;
    }
```

later in the code this is called

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < dataPerSample; i++)
        {
            returned = returned + (weight[i] * learningData[givenColumn].data[i]);
        }
```

all variables are within bounds, sometimes the code works, sometimes I get a nulptr exception at learningData[givenColumn].data[i], tried to have same givenColumn 2 times in a row and the exception was thrown sometimes in the second one, not the first.

Appreciated

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing the actual and expected behaviour.

Comment: Take the easy option, use `std::vector<float>` and `std::vector<ColumData>`.

Comment: How certain are you that `givenColumn` is in-bounds? Your bug is probably in the code you didn't post.

Comment: I am certain of the bounds, when I changed the code to use vector all worked well. thanks